# When I must use "over" instead "about"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

For instance:

> *New reports **over** the Lisa murder.*

In text above, when I'd use *over* instead *about*?

Are there some *diference of usage* between in those two words in the example text above? If so, what? Could you explain me in detail?

Comment: Reports are more frequently ON, OF and ABOUT.  OVER is unusual but signifies exactly the same as ON and ABOUT.  OF is more often used to introduce a first report. **We are getting reports OF an incident at the city hall.**

Comment: Why do you think "over" can mean "about"? The closest example I can think of is "*crying **over** spilled milk*", but I don't know if it applies to any verb other than "cry"

Comment: @gotube I imagine the use of "cry over" meaning "mourn for" comes from literally crying over a dead person, and has become an idiom of its own now

Comment: It looks like a calque from Spanish to me and I would avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, **over** and **about** can be used interchangeably in your context.

[Over (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/over):

> **Over** *preposition* (connected with):
>
> > (referring to a cause of interest, worry, discussion, etc.) connected with or
> > about:

[About (Cambridge Dictionary):](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/about):

> **About** *preposition* (connected with):
>
> > on the subject of, or connected with:

In your example:

> New reports **over/about** the Lisa murder

Both are grammatically correct and have the same meaning.

There are also other words that can be followed by *over* and *about* without changing their meaning, for instance:

> Alan and Bob kept arguing **over** the story.
> Alan and Bob kept arguing **about** the story.

> Carlos had some problems **over** his health.
> Carlos had some problems **about** his health.

> We should spend some time to talk **over** your test result.
> We should spend some time to talk **about** your test result.

Comment: "Carlos had some problems over his health" sounds very strange to this US English speaker.  Can you find some source that supports your claim?  Also, I strongly disagree that "new reports over X" is correct or fluent.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which one's more formal?

Comment: @stangdon So is that why you downvote?

Comment: @stangdon So why do you think that I'm wrong? Can you find some source that supports your claim?

Comment: @ITTSUTFSA  I am a highly educated native speaker, and that's my opinion.

Comment: @ITTSUTFSA FWIW, [Google Ngrams shows results for **new reports of/on/about/concerning/regarding** but nothing for *new reports over*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+reports+concerning%2Cnew+reports+of%2Cnew+reports+on%2Cnew+reports+regarding%2Cnew+reports+about%2Cnew+reports+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnew%20reports%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%20reports%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%20reports%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%20reports%20regarding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%20reports%20about%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @stangdon I am also a highly educated native speaker from the USA, and that's my opinion as well.

Comment: @stangdon How about [reports over](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reports+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creports%20over%3B%2Cc0)? It doesn't necessarily has to be "new"?